# Do we have abstract functions that can be set as private in subclass - TS?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

In TS is there any way to define a abstract class that has a "private" abstract function that then can be declared as private in a subclass like this:

```
abstract class Person{
  //You can imagine adding the privateSubClass keyword or something similar here
  abstract print(): void
}

class Max extends Person {
  private print() {
    console.log("My name is...")
  }
}
```

This example of course wont work because -

```
Class 'Max' incorrectly extends base class 'Person'.
  Property 'print' is private in type 'Max' but not in type 'Person'
```

But adding the private keyword to the abstract function doesnt make sense because then the function: A. Has no logic B. Cant be changed by a subclass. In theory atleast. So is there any workaround to this or any feature request like this going on that I missed?

Comment: And do you not want `protected`?

Comment: A private abstract method doesn't make sense. A class _cannot_ call a private member of its own superclass. So an abstract private method of an abstract class makes even less sense. This sounds a bit like [an XY problem.](https://xyproblem.info/) What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am guess I am trying to achieve what a protected function does but without the fact that the abstract class has access to the subclass function